# Parsing result from file_get_contents('php://input')

Tags: php, arrays

I'm using `file_get_contents('php://input')` to retrieve all the POST parameters/values from a particular web service, e.g.:

```
$postText = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

which results in something like this:

```
inReplyToId=MG1133&to=61477751386&body=test&from=61477751386&messageId=166594397&rateCode=
```

I then need to get each of the individual key/value pairs as I need to set them into fields in a new database record. For example I would like to end up with:

```
$inReplyToId = MG1133
$to = 61477751386
$body = test
```

Once I know the individual value I can set the corresponding field in the database. I would normally use:

```
if(isset($_POST['inReplyToId']) && $_POST['inReplyToId'] !== '' ) {
    $request->setField('_kf_GatewayMessageID', $_POST['inReplyToId']);
}
```

But that won't work in this case as it's not a `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` form that is being submitted.

Comment: [`parse_str()`](http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php

Comment: why use `file_get_contents` and `php://input`? Would it be better to use [data filter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.filter.php) on `INPUT_POST` or `serialize($_POST)` what's the difference?

Comment: $_POST is not available in this particular case as I'm receiving a HTTP POST but it's not a application/x-www-form-urlencoded form data that is being posted.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [`parse_str`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) function to parse query string:

```
$queryString = 'inReplyToId=MG1133&to=61477751386&body=test&from=61477751386&messageId=166594397&rateCode=';
$data = array();
parse_str($queryString, $data);
var_dump($data);
```

**Edit:**

> For example I would like to end up with:
>
> ```
> $inReplyToId = MG1133
> $to = 61477751386
> $body = test
> ```

To get array keys as variable you can use [`extract`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php):

```
extract($data);
```

**Edit 2**: If you already have code that uses `$_POST` variable with respective indexes you can merge data with it:

```
$_POST = array_merge($data, $_POST);
```

But modifing these variables is not advisable.

Answer (score 2):

**You can use this code! try!**

```
<?php
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input"); 
//$postdata = '{"mail": "mistermuhittin@gmail.com", "number": 6969 }';

$obj = json_decode($postdata); 
echo $obj->{'mail'}; // mistermuhittin@gmail.com

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [parse_str()](http://php.net/parse_str) function, which coverts a parameterized string, into an associative array.